# Convert date to Decimal Format in hive

Tags: date, hive

I am new to hive and try to convert date which is in standard 'YYYY-MM-DD' format but i want output in YYYYMMDD format.

For example: "2014-12-25" should return 20141225.

I am trying something similar to given below:

CONCAT(year(start_date),month(start_date),day(start_date))

But this is throwing error as ParseException line 2:0 cannot recognize input near year '(' .

Can anybody suggest some alternate to this?

Comment: "But this is throwing some error" isn't enough information. *What* error? (When you go to the doctor, you don't just say "There's something wrong with me" - you describe the symptoms. The same is true here.)

Comment: Right, so put that in your *question*, ideally with a more complete piece of code which would allow others to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: This is confirmed to be a bug with Hive 0.14 and the new caching stuff. This will be resolved with 0.14.1 and 0.15 but, for the time being, can be fixed by turning off caching:

set hive.cache.expr.evaluation=false;

### Old message below

I encountered the same issue and have opened a ticket on Hive's jira.

I have tested concat+date functions on 0.14 and 0.13 and it only appears to be an issue that was introduced in 0.14.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-9459

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some weird behavior with `CONCAT` that I have not yet been able to fully diagnose, but you can use regular expressions as an alternative.  I loaded up a test table named `test` with the example date you gave in your question:

```
hive> describe test;
OK
start_date              date                                        
Time taken: 0.719 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> select * from test;
OK
2014-12-25
Time taken: 0.206 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Two possible approaches (for the following options, I'm testing on HDP 2.2 with Hive 0.14):

Use `regexp_replace` if you're confident in how your data is going to be formatted.

```
hive> select regexp_replace(start_date, '-', '') from test;
OK
20141225
Time taken: 0.289 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Alternatively, if your data format is more dynamic, or if you anticipate that it may change later on, using `regexp_extract` might give you more flexibility in case something changes.  This script seems to produce the result you're looking for:

```
SET REGEX="(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2})";
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    regexp_extract(start_date, ${hiveconf:REGEX}, 1),
    regexp_extract(start_date, ${hiveconf:REGEX}, 2),
    regexp_extract(start_date, ${hiveconf:REGEX}, 3)
  )
FROM test;
```

I got very strange behavior when I tried to use `CONCAT` together with the `YEAR`/`MONTH`/`DAY` extraction functions - I agree that those should be working the way you're trying to use them, but hopefully `regexp_replace` or `regexp_extract` gives you a viable workaround.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with `CONCACT`.  A simple google search show that that particular function takes a `STRING` and the functions `day`, `month`, and `year` return `INT`s.
  Just simply do

```
CONCAT(split(start_date, '\\-')[0]
     , split(start_date, '\\-')[1]
     , split(start_date, '\\-')[2])
```

Comment: The weirdness I was observing with `CONCAT` persisted even when I explicitly casted the results of `year`, `month`, and `day` as strings - `concat(cast(year(start_date) as string), cast(...` - the concatenated result would always be three copies of the first parameter (so "201420142014" in the sample data).  Do you have insight into what I or the OP might be doing that causes that?